# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: image, maven, spring-mvc

I have an application (Spring 4 MVC+Hibernate 4+MySQL+Maven integration example using annotations) , integrating Spring with Hibernate using annotation based configuration .
I have a maven project with this structure :

[image]

I'd like to reach the `home.png` image via `http://xxx.xxx.221.107:8080/myApp/images/home.png`, but I get a 404

unzipping the war the image is there: **myapp/images/home.png**

I've tried as well addind this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"fr.devices"})
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }


    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }


    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

and moving all the static files into /webapp/resources/
and from the jsp

```
<img src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/images/home.png" width="136" height="43"   />
```

with the same result

Comment: Can you print and check `${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}` value?

Comment: the context path of the app.

Comment: try without <c:out> tag. <img src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/images/home.png" width="136" height="43" />

Comment: 404, as well http://xxx.xxx.221.107:8080myApp/images/home.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add resource handlers configuration please.

For example; Java config

```
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {  
    registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/images/");
   }
}
```

or xml

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/"  cache-period="31556926"/>
```

in JSP

```
 <c:set var="cp" value="${pageContext.request.servletContext.contextPath}" scope="request"></c:set>
 <img src="<c:url value="/images/home.png">" width="136" height="43"  />
```

Comment: It works for me. I wrote it so. the question mark seems. this may be why this isn't working.:)